# Emitter-collector resistance

Tags: bjt

Does the resistance of EMITTER-COLLECTOR changes according to the base current? Or, let's have a constant base current, which is producing a constant (almost) current. Now is this correct to say the emitter-collector resistance is almost zero, since it's passing current? I am asking this because when I'm supplying a base current (but there is no collector supply voltage) and touching the emitter-collector with continuity checker, it beeps, so it feels like at that time the resistance is almost zero.

Comment: Continuity checker on a device which has a power on its own is pretty useless (moreover - can damage your meter). Transistor is an active device. (Ohmic) Resistance is a property of passive devices.

Comment: @Eugene Sh., There is no power on in the OP's circuit... It is just an open-collector transistor that is supplied by the internal voltage source of the continuity checker (ohmmeter). In this arrangement, a voltage source V is loaded by a current-stabilizing non-linear element (the collector-emitter part of the transistor) that keeps up a constant current I (set by the base current or voltage). So, the voltage source has the illusion that it is loaded by an ohmic resistor with resistance R = V/I.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist From the question: *I am asking this because when I'm supplying a base current( but there is no collector supply voltage)...*

Comment: @Eugene Sh., OK, I see... but the paradox here is that the collector of the OP's transistor is still supplied by the ommeter... only it is not clear whether with the correct polarity:) Interesting cases are those that help to gain ideas about the behavior of elements... even at the cost of damage...

Comment: @Circuitfantasist Sure, this is exactly the problem that the ohmmeter is becoming an active element of the circuit and is both affecting and affected by it.

Comment: Yes, never thought that actually collector voltage is itself supplied by the instrument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand this you need to look at this sort of graph for a BJT: -

[image]

Picture from [here](https://41j.com/blog/2014/12/npn-bjt-common-emitter-inverting-amplifier/).

So, choose the line that most corresponds with the base current you are using and see how how much collector current you might have for a given applied collector-emitter voltage.

> (if we) *have a constant base current , which is producing a constant (almost)
> current, now is this correct to say the emitter-collector resistance
> is almost zero, since it's passing current?*

We would say that the collector-emitter resistance is high when the BJT is biased in the way you describe. This is because even though the collector-emitter voltage may be increased, there is still pretty much the same collector current.

We refer to this as the dynamic impedance of the BJT in that \$\dfrac{\Delta V_{CE}}{\Delta I_C}\$ is quite high.

> *but there is no collector supply voltage*

Yes there is; the continuity tester may be producing a volt or so.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the resistance of EMITTER-COLLECTOR changes according to the base
> current?

Explaining the transistor behavior in terms of resistance is a powerful approach for understanding... but we must be careful because (the output part of) the transistor is not a simple (ohmic) resistor but a nonlinear "resistor" having a property to keep the current constant. How does it do this magic? The trick is very simple.

If we apply a voltage V across an ordinary ohmic resistor with resistance R, according to Ohm's law, a current I = V/R will flow. In contrast to this 19-century *static resistor*, the transistor is a *dynamic resistor* that changes its resistance when the voltage across or current through it changes. For example, if the (collector-emitter) voltage increases, the transistor increases its present collector-emitter resistance with the same rate of change; so the current does not change - I = Vinc/Rinc = V/R = const. So, the voltage varies but the current is constant ... and this "misleads" the voltage source that the transistor resistance is infinitely high. This is the situation in the OP's arrangement.

Here is a fun [Wikibooks story](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Circuit_Idea/Group_67b#Lab_3:_Transistor_circuits_(%22inventing%22_a_BJT_current_mirror)) from 2008 that describes how my students studied this phenomenon in the lab in order to reinvent the BJT current mirror.